# Подскажите как правильно синхронизировать индекс в массиве и элемент в объекте массива?

Tags: javascript

Возможно запутал вопросом поэтому прикреплю скриншот.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Задача в том, что вводя в форму текст, получаем вкладку с введённым текстом (а-ля записная книжка).

В данном примере было введёно 5 кусков текста (соответственно создано 5 вкладок с информацией), каждый раз нажимая энтер в консоль выводится массив в котором содержится объект - в котором находится id (динамически меняющийся на 1 вверх) и введённое значение в форму.

При удалении вкладки с текстом, должен так же выводится массив, однако в нём должен быть удалён объект в кот. содержится текст который был в удалённой вкладке.

Проблема и вопрос в том, что в первом удалении всё окей т.к. динамический id у всех вкладок идёт от нуля до `n` вкладок, удалив например 5 вкладку вначале всё окей, т.к. id был 4 и объект был 4ым, далее я удаляю 2 вкладку с id 1, по индексу в массиве это 2 объект - всё окей, далее удаляю 1 вкладку с id 0, в массиве это 1 объект всё окей - остаётся 2 вкладки с id 2 и id 3, при их удалении у меня на руках соответствующие цифры id (это их data-id у li-шек) но в массиве у меня осталось 2 объекта и у них id - это 0 и 1, соответственно удалив вкладки функция будет пытаться удалить то - чего нет...

Мне нужно каким то образом исходя из удалённых вкладок и объектов в массиве иметь чёткую идентификацию текущего удаляемого элемента чтобы корректно его удалять и из массива. Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: используйте структуру ключ-значение

Answer (score 1):

Нужно после удаления элемента массива обновить id следующих за ним элементов в массиве.

```js
let array = [
  {id:0},
  {id:1},
  {id:2},
];

function removeElement(arr, i) {
  arr.splice(i, 1);
  for (;i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].id = i;
  }
}

removeElement(array, 1);
console.log(array);
```